# How to build a jibri docker image from unstable build?

Tags: docker, docker-image, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Jitsi recently release a build [5207](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/commit/fbfaed07b249bd6c2e8d969b76d374c73dd3f85c) which supports streaming to any server. This build is currently unstable and docker-jitsi-meet uses `stable-5142`. Now I want to build jibri docker image using 5207 build. I don't know where to make the changes to build the jibri docker image using unstable build.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to create a docker image from unstable build. Below are the steps.

1. First create a docker image for `base` using unstable build. Go to `base` directory and run `make JITSI_RELEASE=unstable JITSI_REPO=myimage` **OR** You can use `export JITSI_RELEASE=unstable` and `export JITSI_REPO=myimage` will result in `myimage/base:latest`. I followed second approach here.
2. Now we have to create `base-java` image from `myimage/base`. for this we have change `ARG JITSI_REPO=jitsi` to `ARG JITSI_REPO=myimage` in `Dockerfile` in `base-java` directory. Now run `make` command. It will create `myimage/base-java:latest`
3. Now got to `jibri` directory and change `ARG JITSI_REPO=jitsi` to `ARG JITSI_REPO=myimage` in `Dockerfile` and finally run `make` command.

**NOTE**

Start the jibri container and check the jibri version using command `docker exec docker-jitsi-meet_jibri_1 dpkg -l | grep jibri`

**UPDATE**

Simply run **`FORCE_REBUILD=1 JITSI_RELEASE=unstable JITSI_REPO=your_dockerhub_username make`** command from `docker-jitsi-meet` directory. No need to do anything else. You can control which image to build by editing this [line](https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet/blob/ec570baee661838622e69735a5aa26123a4bd769/Makefile#L5). `base` and `base-java` images are mandatory hence don't remove them from file.